# In Spring Security OpenID, How can I get to user detail informations?

Tags: spring-security, openid

In Spring Security OpenID, How can I get to user detail informations?(email, firstname, ..)

except  ! I want to get these in java or jsp file, not xml file.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called Attribute Exchange. It's a feature of OpenID that allows exchange of user registration data (e.g. name, email,...) from a provider. NOTE: the list of supported attribute exchange values is different from one provider to the next.

Assuming you have Spring Security with OpenID configured and working, enabling Attribute Exchange is pretty trivial.

```
<!--in your spring config -->
<openid-login ....>
  <!-- here is sample config for getting email -->
  <attribute-exchange> 
   <openid-attribute 
      name="email" 
      type="http://schema.openid.net/contact/email" 
      required="true"
   /> 
  </attribute-exchange>
</openid-login>
```

Spring will save the attribute data into `OpenIDAuthenticationToken`. Then in your *UserDetailsService

```
public UserDetails loadUserDetails(OpenIDAuthenticationToken token) {
  ...
  List<OpenIDAttribute> attributes = token.getAttributes();
  user.setEmail(getAttribute("email", attributes));
  ..
}

private String getAttribute(String attrName, List<OpenIDAttribute> attrs) { 
  //do work to parse for email attribute
}
```

Comment: i know this. but if i use, whenever one user asks login, provider always asks user to access information. i want to get information only first time - user sign-in my site.

Comment: Please update your question to reflect what you want! You asked how to get user detail info - now you're stating you already know this.